# Vedic Temples on Earth's Magnetic Lines

Tags: temple, vastu-shastra, architecture

Is there any mention of Vedic temples being built on Earths magnetic lines? 
**Longitude 79 meridian EAST** seems to have very long list of Ancient Indian Temples built on this specific longitude: 
Kedarnath, Badrinath, Brihadeswara temple, Meenakshi temple Madurai, Arulmigu Rameshwaram, Tungnath temple .... and so on and on and on!

Baijnath, Maha Kaleshwar MP, Kal Bhairav Ujjain, lie on Longitude 76 east.

Comment: What are 'Vedic' temples?

Comment: Yes... Temples are built based on geography, 9 planets rays influence on Earth etc. EX: Pazhani Mountain Muruga temple  - has mars planet rays falling over there. So very well Vedic temples can be built specifically based on geography positions of Earth.!!!

Comment: This is not scientific speculation.  Mercury to Jupiter very much part of hinduism and vedas have this explanation.  So understand the question before close voting!

Comment: @Sarvabhouma : I used the term 'Vedic temples' loosely. I mean Ancient Hindu Temples.
Akshay : The magnetic lines are hard scientific fact, accepted by modern Physics. Ancient Indian traditions also refer to  the Magnetic Poles of Earth & even advice to sleep ALIGNED to the North -South direction, with the feet towards North & head towards South.